# $\sum_{p} \chi(p)/p$ is conditionally convergent for non-principal character

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $\chi$ is a non-principal character. Show that the sum $\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is conditionally convergent. Then show that the product $\prod_{p}(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p})^{-1}$ is conditionally convergent to $L(1,\chi)$.

Using summation by parts, I can show that $\sum_{n}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}$ is conditionally convergent. But it seems that the method cannot be applied to $\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ since $\frac{1}{n}1_{\mathcal{P}}(n)$ is not monotone.

Answer (score 2):

Use partial summation to show that
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\chi(p)}{p} = \frac{1}{x \log x} \sum_{p \leq x} \chi(p) \log p - \int_{2}^{x} \frac{\log t + 1}{t^2 (\log t)^2} \sum_{p \leq t} \chi(p) \log p \, dt.\]
Now
\[\sum_{p \leq x} \chi(p) \log p = \sum_{n \leq x} \chi(n) \Lambda(n) + O\left(\sqrt{x} \log x\right).\]
Via the usual methods as for proving the prime number theorem, one can then show that
\[\sum_{n \leq x} \chi(n) \Lambda(n) = O\left(x e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)\]
if $\chi$ is nonprincipal. (Note that this is by far the hardest part; it's essentially equivalent to the prime number theorem in arithmetic progressions, which in turn is essentially equivalent to the nonvanishing of $L(s,\chi)$ along the line $\Re(s) = 1$. A standard reference for this estimate is chapter 11 of Montgomery and Vaughan.)

This implies the result, because then the first term in the earlier expression for $\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is $o(1)$ and the second term is
\[\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{\log t + 1}{t^2 (\log t)^2} \sum_{p \leq t} \chi(p) \log p \, dt - \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\log t + 1}{t^2 (\log t)^2} \sum_{p \leq t} \chi(p) \log p \, dt,\]
and the first integral is some finite number and the second is $o(1)$ due to the bound $\sum_{p \leq x} \chi(p) \log p = O\left(x e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$.

EDIT: Note that for $\Re(s) > 1$,
\[\log L(s,\chi) = \log \prod_p \frac{1}{1 - \chi(p) p^{-s}} = \sum_p \log \frac{1}{1 - \chi(p) p^{-s}} = \sum_p \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{k p^{ks}}\]
via the Euler product for $L(s,\chi)$ and the Taylor series expansion for $\log$. All of this is justified because $\Re(s) > 1$, so everything is absolutely convergent. It follows that for $\Re(s) > 1$,
\[\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s} = \log L(s,\chi) - \sum_p \sum_{k = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(p)^k}{k p^{ks}}.\]
The sum on the right-hand side is absolutely convergent for $\Re(s) > 1/2$, and so defines a holomorphic function on this right-half plane. Moreover, by the zero-free region for $L(s,\chi)$, $\log L(s,\chi)$ defines a holomorphic function in the same zero-free region. It follows by analytic continuation that the left-hand side extends to a holomorphic function in this same zero-free region.

In spite of all of this, one cannot conclude immediately this holomorphic function is equal to $\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ when $s = 1$, and so this sum converges conditionally. It does show however that the limit $\lim_{s \to 1^+} \sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}$ exists.

Comment: did you read my answer ?

Comment: @user1952009, yes, but it didn't really answer the question. It is a nontrivial step in going from the fact that $L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic and nonvanishing on $\Re(s) \geq 1$ to showing that $\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ converges as $x \to \infty$. The proof requires partial summation, as in my answer.

Comment: honestly, I don't see the point of your answer/comment. if you want to be useful, try to see if once we have $\ln L(s,\chi)$ holomorphic on $Re(s) \ge 1$, we need first the functional equation for $L(s,\chi)$ and then evaluating the density of zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ in the critical strip, in order to be ready for proving the explicit formula $\sum_{ n \le x} \Lambda(n) \chi(n) = \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} x^s\frac{L'}{L}(s,\chi) ds =  -\sum_{L(\rho,\chi) = 0} \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$ with the residue theorem, and finally $\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ converges, or if we can do it faster.

Comment: @user1952009, yes, I am well aware that you need to find a zero-free region for $L(s,\chi)$ (though this does not actually require the functional equation) in order to show the desired bounds for $\sum_{n \leq x} \chi(n) \Lambda(n)$. This is completely standard analytic number theory.

Comment: what you wrote is really really basic and doesn't help at all ! if you don't know simply say "I don't know" and don't write an answer (or explain precisely what you know and think could be helpful)

Comment: @user1952009, are you serious? This question is trivial to me (I am an active researcher in analytic number theory). I posted my answer because the OP commented on your answer asking how the result follows from what you wrote. In particular, as I mentioned, just because $\log L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic on $\Re(s) \geq 1$ does not mean automatically that $\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is conditionally convergent. You have to use partial summation, which you don't mention in your answer.

Comment: I did not write up the details for $\sum_{n \leq x} \chi(n) \Lambda(n) = O(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}})$ because (a) you'd pretty much covered that in your answer, more or less, and (b) it's a standard result (chapter 11 of Montgomery and Vaughan).

Comment: @user1952009, honestly, I don't understand what your objection to my answer is. Yes, it is extremely basic, but it answers the question, which yours does not. If you are going to downvote, please tell me what exactly is wrong with it.

Comment: is it a joke ? it doesn't answer at all to the question, whereas I know a way to prove the question and tried to explain it  : prove that $\ln L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic for $Re(s) \ge 1$, prove the explicit formula for $\sum_{n \le x} \Lambda(n) \chi(n)$, and voila $\sum_p \chi(p)/p$ converges. I detailed only the first step because I'm not sure the other steps are really needed, and I assume you already know those steps because you already proved the prime number theorem.

Comment: @user1952009, let's continue this discussion in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38926/discussion-between-peter-humphries-and-user1952009

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I came up with a solution, could you mind checking it?

Answer (score 2):

We can use the following estimate which only needs the fact that $L(1,\chi)$ doesn't vanish for non-principal character:
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda(n)\chi(n)}{n}=O_{\chi}(1)\quad (1)
$$
for any $x\geq 1$ and non-principal character $\chi$ (see [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/254a-notes-1-elementary-multiplicative-number-theory/) Theorem 70).

Note that 
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda (n)\chi(n)}{n}=\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log (p)\chi(p)}{p}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\sum_{p\leq x^{1/j}}\frac{\log (p)\chi(p^j)}{p^j}.$$
We crudely bound $\frac{\log p\chi(p^j)}{p^j}\ll \frac{1}{2^{j/2}}\frac{\log p}{p^{3/2}}$ for $j\geq 2$. Since $\sum_{n}\frac{\log n}{n^{3/2}}=O(1)$, we obtain
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\Lambda (n)\chi(n)}{n}=\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log p\chi(p)}{p}+O_\chi(1).$$
It follows from $(1)$  that
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\log p\chi(p)}{p}=O_{\chi}(1).$$
Now we use summation by parts to obtain
$$\sum_{x\leq p\leq y}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}=\sum_{x\leq p\leq y}\frac{\log p\chi(p)}{p}\frac{1}{\log y}-\int_{x}^y\sum_{x\leq y\leq t}\frac{\log p\chi(p)}{p}-\frac{1}{t\log^2 t}\,dt.$$
Since $\sum_{x\leq p\leq  t}\frac{\log p\chi(p)}{p}=O(1)$ for all $x\leq t\leq y$, we have
$$\sum_{x\leq p\leq y}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}=O(\frac{1}{\log y}+\frac{1}{\log x}),$$
here I omit $\chi$ in the big O. We see from  [Cauchy's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test) that $\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}$ is convergent.

To show that $\prod_{p}(1-\frac{\chi(p}{p})^{-1}$ is conditionally convergent to $L(1,\chi)$. Taking logarithm, it suffices to show that 
$$\log L(1,\chi)=-\sum_{p}\log(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}).$$
Since $(1,\chi)\neq 0$, we have $\log(s,\chi)$ is holomprhic on a neighborhood of $s=1$, it follows that $\log L(1,\chi)=\lim_{s\to 1^+}\log L(s,\chi)$. Thus it suffices to show
$$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\log L(s,\chi)=-\sum_{p}\log (1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}).$$
Note that 
\begin{align}\log L(s,\chi)&=\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\sum_p\frac{\chi(p)^j}{jp^{sj}}\\
&=\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}+\text{something continuous on }\mathrm{Re}(s)> \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
for $s>1$ and 
$$-\log(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p})=\sum_p\frac{\chi(p)}{p}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\sum_p\frac{\chi(p)^j}{jp^j}.$$
thus it suffices to show that 
$$\lim_{s\to 1^+}\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}=\sum_{p}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}.$$
To show this, we  mimic the proof of [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). By partial summation, we have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n^s}-\frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}\right)&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-1\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}\left(\frac{1}{p_N^{s-1}}-1\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}}\right).
\end{align}
Sending $N$ to infinity, we obtain
\begin{align}\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}-\sum_p\frac{\chi(p)}{p}&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}}\right)\\
=&-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}}\right)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}}\right).
\end{align}
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}$ is convergent, for every $\varepsilon>0$, we can choose $n$ sufficiently large (say $n\geq N$ for some $N$) such that $|\sum_{n+1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k}|\leq\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$, thus we have
$$\left|\sum_{n\geq N}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k}\right)\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}}\right)\right|\leq\varepsilon\sum_{n\geq N}\left(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}}\right)\leq\varepsilon.$$
It remains to control $-(1-\frac{1}{2^{s-1}})\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_n)}{p_n}$ and $\sum_{n< N}(\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{\chi(p_k)}{p_k})(\frac{1}{p_n^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{p_{n+1}^{s-1}})$, these two functions are continuous at $s=1$, thus we can choose $s$ sufficiently close to $1$ to make them less than $\varepsilon$. The claim then follows.

Comment: +1, The result you are trying to prove is equivalent to the non-vanishing of $L(1,\chi)$/Dirichlet's theorem. Note however that proving the estimate you refer to from Tao's blog (Theorem 70) is the heart of this question, and Dirichlet's theorem. Quoting that proof from elsewhere skips over the important details about why this result is true.

Answer (score -1):

complicated. there is a proof sketch when $\chi$ is a non-principal non-quadratic character (i.e. when it is a complex valued character) :

- the main trick is to use that $\frac{1}{\chi(q)}\sum_{\chi \pmod q} \chi(n) =  \delta_{\ n \ \equiv\  1 \pmod q}$ (the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of size $\phi(q)$)

  and that $L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic (on $ Re(s) > 0$ is enough and easy to prove) whenever $\chi$ is not the principal character $\chi_0$ (i.e. $\chi_0(n)=1$ whenever $gcd(n,q)$).

  hence if $\chi \ne \chi_0$ and $\lim_{s \to 1^+} \sum_p \chi(p)/p^s$ diverges then $L(s,\chi)$ has a $0$ at $s=1$,

  but if it is a non real character then the character comes with its complex conjugate $\overline{\chi}$ which in that case also has a zero at $s=1$, and hence two terms of the product
  $$F_q(s) = \prod_{\chi \pmod q} L(s,\chi)$$
  would have a zero at s=1, but only $L(s,\chi_0)$ has a pole at $s=1$, of order $1$, hence $F_q(s)$ has a zero at $s=1$, a contradiction since :
  $$\ln F_q(s) = \phi(q) \sum_{p^k \equiv 1 \pmod q} \frac{1}{k p^{k s}}$$
  which diverges to $+\infty$ when $s \to 1^+$.
- then prove that $L(s,\chi)$ doesn't have any zero on $Re(s) =1$, using the same argument as for  $\zeta(s)$ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch

  which is based on the same kind of trick : that $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic, that it doesn't have any pole on $Re(s) = 1, s \ne 1$, and that $\ln \zeta(s)$ is a Dirichlet series with non-negative coefficients, hence using $$\zeta(x)^3\zeta(x+iy)^4\zeta(x+2iy)|=\exp\sum_{n,p}\frac{3+4\cos(ny\log p) +\cos (2ny\log p)}{np^{nx}}\ge 1$$ if it had a zero at $1+it$ it would have a pole at $1+2it$, a contradiction.
- and you will  be ready for proving the prime number theorem for
  Dirichlet L-functions when $\chi$ is a complex character, i.e. that $\ln L(s,\chi)$ is holomoprhic on $Re(s) \ge 1$, and hence that $$\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p}$$ converges.
- when $\chi$ is the real non-principal (quadratic) character, I don't remember how we prove that it doesn't have a zero at $s=1$, see for example Terrence tao blog  https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/254a-notes-1-elementary-multiplicative-number-theory/ just after the corollary 77.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to prove $L(1,\chi)$ doesn't vanish for all non-principal characters (see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/254a-notes-1-elementary-multiplicative-number-theory/) ).  But why the divergence of $\sum_p \chi(p)/p$  implies $L(s,\chi)$ has a zero at $s=1$.

Comment: no, that $\sum_p \chi(p) p^{-s}$ is holomorphic on $Re(s) \ge 1$ implies that it converges on $Re(s)  = 1$, that's why I also mentioned how to prove $L(s,\chi) $ doesn't have any zero on $Re(s) = 1$

Comment: @XiangYu (not only at $s=1$ but on the whole line $Re(s)=1$)

Comment: You proved that $\lim_{s\to 1^+} \sum_p\chi(p)/p^s$ exits, then how to infer $\sum_p\chi(p)/p$ converges? is there something missing?

Comment: @XiangYu : yes, you are missing the fact that from the localization of the zeros/poles of a Dirichlet L-function we infer the explicit formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_formulae_(L-function)#Riemann.27s_explicit_formula and hence the convergence of the series for $\ln L(s,\chi)$ or $\frac{L'}{L}(s,\chi)$

Comment: @XiangYu : and I "proved it" not only when $s \to 1^+$ but when $s \to 1+it$ for every $t$

Comment: @XiangYu : it seems that the simplest trick for jumping from $f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$ holomorphic on $Re(s) \ge 1$ to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-1-it}$ converges is detailed in  [Titchmarsh's book page 60 to 66](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Titchmarsh_TheTheoryoftheRiemannZeta-Function.pdf) and is that for $c > 0$ : $$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} \frac{(x/n)^z}{z} dz =  \delta_{n<x}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{(x/n)^{c}}{T \ln(x/n)})$$ hence multiplying by $a_n n^{-1-it}$ and summing : $$\frac1{2i\pi}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} f(1+it+z) \frac{dz}{z} = \sum_{n < x}a_n n^{-1-it}+\mathcal{O}(\ldots)$$

Comment: As I mentioned in chat, this is called Perron's inversion formula, and after this step, one still needs to estimate the integral. The standard way is to use the zero-free region for the Dirichlet series in the integrand and use Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: @PeterHumphries : the Perron inversion formula is with $T = \infty$ (i.e. the inverse Laplace transform). and it seems we need the zero-free region and an estimate of $|f(s)|$ in the region $Re(s) > 1-\frac{A}{\log Im(s)}$, putting all this together to say "when $f(s)$ is of a certain type it works, but when $f(s)$ is of another type it doesn't" would be helpful but I don't feel capable yet