# How to prove that $\sqrt{3}\pi/6=\prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod{6}} \frac{p}{p-1}\prod_{p \equiv 5 \pmod{6}} \frac{p}{p+1}$ with $p \in \mathbb{P}$?

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, euler-product

I would like to prove the formula $$\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{6}=\left(\prod_{\substack{p \equiv 1 \pmod{6} \\ p \in \mathbb{P}}} \frac{p}{p-1}\right) \cdot \left(\prod_{\substack{p \equiv 5 \pmod{6} \\ p \in \mathbb{P}}} \frac{p}{p+1}\right)=\frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{7}{6} \cdot \frac{11}{12} \cdot \frac{13}{12} \cdot \frac{17}{18} \cdots ,$$ it appears listed on the wikipedia article [List of formulae involving π#Infinite products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80#Infinite_products), I put a citation needed tag on it and left a message on the [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:Poliagapitos) page of the user who added the formula but this was 5 months ago and is unlikely to get an answer as this formula is that user only [edit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/Poliagapitos) ever so it looks more like throw away account.

Numerically the formula seems to be correct so my guess is that it was taken from some paper or that it is not that hard to prove, I don't much about this stuff my only idea was try something to similar to the [dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function) $\beta(s) = \prod_{p \equiv 1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ 4} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \ \mathrm{mod} \ 4} \frac{1}{1 + p^{-s}}$ since $\beta(1)=\pi/4$ like this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149203/how-does-one-compute-the-euler-product-for-the-dirichlet-beta-function) but couldn't make it work mod 6 so I got nowhere. Also looked for the formula with approach0.xyz/searchonmath.com but couldn't find it either.

The code "Product[Piecewise[{{p/(p - 1), Element[p, Primes] && Mod[p, 6] == 1}}, 1], {p, 2, 1000}] Product[Piecewise[{{p/(p + 1), Element[p, Primes] && Mod[p, 6] == 5}}, 1], {p, 2, 1000}]" can be used on wolfram online to [evaluate](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/063af96d-6279-4159-a4aa-8e6c82a40666) the series (Thanks to
@J.M.can'tdealwithit who provided me with code over the mathematica stackexchange chat)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing [$L(s,\chi)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function)${}=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}=\sum_{n>0}\chi(n)n^{-s}$ for $\Re s>1$, where $$\chi(n):=\begin{cases}1,&n\equiv1\pmod{6}\\-1,&n\equiv-1\pmod{6}\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ the claim follows from the ability to take $s\to1^+$ (a [non-trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1759688) result!), since $$\sum_{n>0}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^1(x^{6n}-x^{6n+4})\,dx=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^4}{1-x^6}\,dx=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}$$ (an elementary way, or using $\int_0^1\frac{t^{a-1}-t^{-a}}{1-t}\,dt=\pi\cot a\pi$ at $a=1/6$ after $t=x^6$).

Comment: This does the trick and I follow it so I'm accepting it (of course if anybody else has another solution I will still be happy to read and upvote it). This is my fault but I still have some doubts that maybe you can help me with if it isn't too much trouble, thing is for β(s) I have the next sequence of steps:

Comment: $\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(4n+1)^s}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_4(n)}{n^s}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-\chi_4(p)p^{-1}}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-\sin(\frac{p\pi}2)p^{-s}}$ so for $\beta_6(s)$ I wanted to do the same but didn't know how to write the series in the first step or the product at the end:
$\beta_6(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ?=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(6n+1)^s}-\frac{1}{(6n+5)^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_6(n)}{n^s}=\prod_p \frac{p^s}{p^s-\chi_6(p)}=\prod_p \frac{1}{1-?p^{-s}}$

Comment: Had a notification in my phone of a message you left, I read something about you not following me but when I pressed on it and came here the message was no longer so couldn't really read it, this is my failing to understand rather than something of substance so actually don't worry about answering, but I have still the urge to explain myself a little bit, what I tried to say is that the proof of Leibniz series looks something like :

Comment: $\beta(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_4(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4n+1}-\frac{1}{4n+3}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{2n+1}|_{x=1}=\arctan(1)=\pi/4$ so I thought this case would look something like $\beta_6(1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi_6(n)}{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{6n+1}-\frac{1}{6n+5}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ?_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty ?nx^n|_{x=1}=?(1)=\sqrt{3}\pi/6$ but once again this is just my own confusion and I think the way you proved it works for all kind of chi functions anyways.

Comment: @Dabed: A proof of $\sum_{n>0}\chi(n)n^{-s}=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})^{-1}$ for $\color{red}{\Re s>1}$ and any character $\chi$ runs much like the one for $\chi\equiv 1$ (i.e., for the original Euler product). The **hard** part is that we have $$\lim_{s\to1^+}\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}(1-\chi(p)p^{-s})=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}(1-\chi(p)/p)$$ for a non-principal $\chi$ (together with the fact that the last product converges at all).